# unexpected result from using replace in function (Python)

Tags: python, function, replace

I have written a first code block that I would like to replace with a second code block, a function and a call to that function. I'm having difficulty understanding why they have different results. They should be the same. I guess it has something to do with the behavior of "replace" in a function.

```
# 1st code block
amount_units = ["mg", "/kg"]
expression = "100 mg/kg"
expression_store = "100 mg/kg"

for amount_unit in amount_units:
    if amount_unit in expression:
        expression_store = expression_store.replace(amount_unit, ' amount_unit ')

print(expression_store)
# result:
# 100  amount_unit  amount_unit

# 2nd code block
amount_units = ["mg", "/kg"]
expression = "100 mg/kg"
expression_store = "100 mg/kg"

def types_of_constituent_expression_store(constituent_type_list1, expression1, str1, expression_store1):
    for constituent_type1 in constituent_type_list1:
        if constituent_type1 in expression1:
            expression_store1 = expression_store1.replace(constituent_type1, ' '+str1+' ')

types_of_constituent_expression_store(amount_units, expression, "amount_unit", expression_store)

print(expression_store)
# result:
# 100 mg/kg
```

I tried to run the two blocks of code. I expected that they should produce the same output.

Comment: Why do you expect your second approach to ever change the value of the global variable `expression_store`? Where do you believe in the code that global variable is ever modified after it is defined at the top `expression_store = "100 mg/kg"`? It is never modified.

Comment: I expected it to be modified by the line "expression_store1 = expression_store1.replace(constituent_type1, ' '+str1+' ')" because  "types_of_constituent_expression_store" calls "expression_store" as the value of the argument "expression_store1".

Comment: Inside the function, that is a *local variable*, which has nothing to do with the outside, global variable of the same name (in a different scope), except that you happened to refer to the object when you provided the argument with a variable of the same name. But that's the *whole point of scope*, that the two *variables* are different (although, they may refer to the same object). Re-assigning one of those variables has no effect on the other (of course, if both variables are referring to the same object, and you mutate that object, you'll see the mutation through both variables)

Comment: So, read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I searched online and thought the solution would be to declare "global expression_store" in the function and eliminate "expression_store1" as an argument. That happens to work with the minimal working example I provided, but I actually have a larger script I'm working on that contains this code, and "expression_store" is first declared within a function, so it has intermediate, not global, scope. I get "NameError: name 'expression_store' is not defined". How would you suggest I rewrite the code to get the behavior I expected?

Comment: Seems to be working now. I found that I had to use "nonlocal expression_store".